# How to echo Empty Entry Prohibited Message generated from a query in php?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a form which when submitted, checks this query ->

```
if(isset($_POST['update']) && !empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['reg_name']))
```

I want to echo a message "Please fill up all the required fields." if the required fields are not filled up.

In short, it should highlight the field name which is not filled up.

The Full Code:

```
include ('database/abcd.php');

if ($con->connect_error) 
{
    die("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);
} 

if(isset($_POST['update']))

{

$error = array();
if(empty($_POST['name']))
    $error[] = 'Please fill name field';
if(empty($_POST['reg_name']))
    $error[] = 'Pleae fill reg_name field';
if(count($error) < 1)
{
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $reg_name = $_POST['reg_name'];
    $established = $_POST['established'];
    $industry = $_POST['industry'];
    $about = $_POST['about'];
    $website = $_POST['website'];
    $mail =  $_POST['mail'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $address =  $_POST['address'];
    $city = $_POST['city'];
    $facebook = $_POST['facebook'];
    $wiki = $_POST['wiki'];
    $twitter = $_POST['twitter'];
    $google = $_POST['google'];
    $member_username = $_SESSION['username'];

    $process="INSERT INTO notifications (member_username, process, icon, class) VALUES ('$_POST[member_username]','$_POST[process]','$_POST[icon]','$_POST[class]')";

    if (!mysqli_query($con,$process))
    {
      die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }


    $sql = "UPDATE `company_meta` SET `name` = '$name', reg_name = '$reg_name', wiki = '$wiki', established = '$established', industry = '$industry', about = '$about', website = '$website', mail = '$mail', phone = '$phone', address = '$address', city = '$city', facebook = '$facebook', twitter = '$twitter', google = '$google' WHERE `member_username` = '$member_username'";

    if ($con->query($sql)) 
    {
        header('Location: edit.php');           
    } 
}

else
{  
    $errors = implode(',' $error); 
  echo $errors;   
}

    $con->close();
}
```

Comment: You are joking right?

Comment: Actually i am very new to PHP so do not know that much. Researched a bit but in vain.

Comment: try this `echo  "Please fill up all the required fields.";`  But first try this [The Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/index.php)

Comment: Are you talking about this -> if(isset($_POST['update']) && !empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['reg_name'])) {    } else { echo "Please fill up all the required fields."; }

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
if(isset($_POST['update'])) // This first check whether it is an update call
{
   $error = array();  // Here we initialize an array so that we can put the messages in it.

   if(empty($_POST['name'])) // If the name field is empty, push a message in $error array.
    $error[] = 'Please fill name field';

   if(empty($_POST['reg_name'])) // Same as above field
    $error[] = 'Pleae fill reg_name field';

   if(count($error) < 1) // Now this checks if the $error array has no value. If it has value it means that either or both of the above fields are empty and the else block will be executed.
   {
      // Submit your form
   }
   else
   {
      $errors = implode(',' $error); 
      echo $errors;
   }
}
else
{
    // Update not triggered.
}
```

Comment: see what you are getting in `$_POST`

Comment: @Raheel The code is prohibiting NULL entry, but the echo part is not showing up. I mean it should echo the field which is not filled up.

Comment: @RaheelKhan It only echos "Array" when empty entry is submitted.

Comment: @M.Doye I did it. Now it will be kind of you if you can please remove the downvote. Thanks

Comment: @ArijitAich where did you place echo ?

Comment: @ArijitAich see how i echo $errors. And you are echoing it without `implode`. Arrays cannot be `echo`. They first have to be converted to string. So i used `implode` function and join the two arrays with a comma.

Comment: Using the implode function i am getting this -> `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$error' (T_VARIABLE) in /****/**********/*******_******/****_********/********/*****/******_******.php on line 612`

Comment: I dont see implode in your updated code. Please mention there how did you write implode

Comment: I did that post updating my code. I have updated the code yet again and its resulting the same.

Comment: your code says `$errors = implode(',' $error); `. I don't see comma between the `implode` params. This should be `$errors = implode(',' , $error); `. Note the comma in between `','` & `$error`.

Comment: You are receiving syntax error because PHP was expecting a comma at that place which you missed.

Comment: I used `if(empty($_POST['name'])){
    $error = 'Please fill name field';
}
 if(empty($_POST['reg_name'])){
    $error = 'Pleae fill reg_name field';
}`
And its working fine. Does this thing have any problem ? I guess both of the codes work the same right ?

Comment: where there is only 1 line of code in a if statement you can use that without `{}` brackets. Both are same.

Comment: Sorry @RaheelKhan my code wasnt working. I updated it with your latest code and it works. Superb !! Thanks Alot.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are pass in name or reg_name is check first .may be name or reg_name can content white space so that it not showing message otherwise above code is working correctly..